# Complex for each to retrieve array values

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I am currently working on a project which creates an array to many dimensions. A print_r() results in such:

```
Array ( 
[campaigns] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [CampaignId] => 1 
        [DID] => 2394434444 
        [FWDDID] => 3214822821 
        [ProductId] => 1 
        [CampaignName] => Fort Myers Bus #1 
        [ProductName] => CallTrack - Sharktek 
        [Active] => 1 [CompanyId] => 1 ) 

    [1] => Array ( 
        [CampaignId] => 4 
        [DID] => 2394434445 
        [FWDDID] => 3214822821 
        [ProductId] => 1 
        [CampaignName] => Cape Coral Billboard #2 
        [ProductName] => CallTrack - Sharktek 
        [Active] => 1 [CompanyId] => 1 ) 

    [2] => Array ( 
        [CampaignId] => 5 
        [DID] => 2392146000 
        [FWDDID] => 3214822821 
        [ProductId] => 1 
        [CampaignName] => Test Campaign 
        [ProductName] => CallTrack - Sharktek 
        [Active] => 1 
        [CompanyId] => 1 )
    ) 
)
```

I am trying to create a foreach loop which select all the CampaignIds and use them in another for each loop, unfortunately, I have not been able to do so.

Because I am using CodeIgniter, I am unable to simple echo the results in the controller, rather I have to pass the values I want to another array to send to the view

Thank you for your time and efforts, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's not that complex, where is your `foreach`?

Comment: I'm trying to write the foreach which would allow me to access CampaignId and use each of them as parameters in another function

Comment: foreach ($data as $row) {
$campaign1 = $row['CampaignId'];
}

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get all CampaignIds to `foreach` over later and you have PHP >= 5.5.0 then use `array_column`:

```
$ids = array_column($array, 'CampaignId');
```

If PHP < 5.5.0 then `foreach` over `$array['campaigns']`.

```
foreach($array['campaigns'] as $campaign) {
    $ids[] = $campaign['CampaignId'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion, I have tried to do the following:

$data['campaigns'] = $this->model_record->retrieve_campaign($CompanyId);
  
$CampaignId = array_column($data, 'CampaignId');
print_r($CampaignId);

and 

$data['campaigns'] = $this->model_record->retrieve_campaign($CompanyId);
  
$CampaignId = array_column($data['campaigns'], 'CampaignId');
print_r($CampaignId);